# Make static files from django's collecstatic part of Docker image

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile, django-staticfiles

I want to include static files generated from `python manage.py collectstatic` in the Docker image.

For this, I included the following line in my `Dockerfile`

```
CMD python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

But since it runs the command in an intermediate container, the generated static files aren't present `STATIC_ROOT` directory. The following lines I can see on the logs of build.

```
Step 13/14 : CMD python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
 ---> Running in 8ea5efada461
Removing intermediate container 8ea5efada461
 ---> 67aef71cc7b6
```

I'd like to include the generated static files in the image. What shall I do to achieve this?

## Update ( solution )

I was using CMD but instead, I should use RUN command for this task as the docs say

`The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the output of `collectstatic` into your final container.

For example, my dockerfile contains the same concept (this isn't the complete dockerfile, just the relevant pieces)

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7.7-slim-buster AS python-base

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

WORKDIR /project
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /requirements.txt

FROM node:8 AS frontend-deps-npm
WORKDIR /
COPY ./package.json /package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN /node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js


FROM python-base AS frontend-deps
COPY --from=frontend-deps-npm /app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN python manage.py collectstatic -v 2 --noinput


FROM python-base AS app
COPY . /app
COPY --from=frontend-deps /app/static-collection /app/static-collection
```

Comment: Yes I am doing that part. But how can we persist the data of the intermediate container? What does the -v flag for the collectstatic command do?

Comment: `-v` is for verbosity. You can ignore that. You're copying the data from the container building the static files to your final container, like I showed on the final line of that snippet?

Comment: No, I'll be copying the generated static files from collectstatic to my container with nginx image to serve it. For this, I am planning to use `COPY --from=shahrukh/learnup:web /var/www/learnup/static_cdn/ /var/www/static/` But since the files don't persist it's not working. Note that I am pushing the built image to docker hub first and then trying to build the nginx image. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Taking the flow as I have detailed above will do what you want. My `frontend-deps` container does `collectstatic` so it contains what you would want. After it's ran, you need to copy that data into the container that will use it. So build your nginx container last, add the static files, expose the right ports & run your service.

Comment: i tried your solution to break it down into multi-stage builds, but still I am getting my static folder as empty even though the command ran successfully and my COPY statement also executed successfully.

Comment: I was making a mistake using CMD to run my collectstatic, instead I should've used a RUN command as the docs says - `The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.`

Comment: Yes, which is why I've got `RUN` in this answer.